# An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'EntityDataSource'

Tags: excel-services, powerpivot

I use SQL Server 2012 SP1 U8 and SharePoint 2013.

- I configure Excel Service and Performance Point Service and PowerPivot Service.
- I create an Excel File`that fetch data from Data Warehouse in PowerPivot report.
- I load this file in Documents in my SharePoint web site.
- When I click on my Excel file in SharePoint, I get this Error:

[image]

> An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 
>   'EntityDataSource'. Verify that the connection information is correct 
>   and that you have   permissions to access the data source.
>
> rsCannotRetrieveModelhttp://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400
>    An
>   error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source
>   'EntityDataSource'. Verify that the connection information is correct
>   and that you have permissions to access the data
>   source.
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;
>   EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&
>   EvtID=rsCannotRetrieveModel&ProdName=
>   Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=11.0.3401.0
>    Microsoft SQL
>   Server Reporting Services 11.0.3401.0
>   127
>   
>   OsIndependent
>   xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
>   1033http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
>   ReportingServicesLibrary 
>   msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
>   LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID
>   =rsCannotRetrieveModel&ProdName= Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=11.0.3401.0"
>   xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">An error
>   occurred  while loading the model for the item or data source
>   'EntityDataSource'.  Verify that the connection information is correct
>   and that you have  permissions to access the data
>   source.
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCorehttp://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&
>   EvtID=rsErrorOpeningConnection&ProdName=
>   Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=11.0.3401.0"
>   xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"> Cannot
>   create a connection to data source 'EntityDataSource'.
>   
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient We cannot locate
>   a server to load the workbook Data Model.
>    We cannot locate a server
>   to load the workbook Data Model.
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices
>   We cannot locate a server to load the workbook Data
>   Model.

I see this [Power View Fails to Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862078/power-view-fails-to-connect) link but the answer does not work for me.

And this Link [Power View Error: An error occurred while loading the model](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/64ca0546-f5c4-4d33-95c1-1cf17ac789de/powerview-error-an-error-occurred-while-loading-the-model-for-the-item-or-data-source?forum=sqlreportingservices)

**Note**: I can see all Excel report that does not have the PowerPivot component.

Answer (score 0):

This is permission issue. You have restricted the user and your model using Window Authentication so that it can not be able to consume data from the model. Give specific rights to user group then this will be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You need to recycle the Security token app pool.

Comment: Can you please add more details to this answer about how to accomplish what you propose?